# How can I change the weights for Gaussian adaptive thresholding in OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

From what I understand, in adaptive thresholding when we use `cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C` , it calculates the mean of the pixel values in the block and that is the threshold value and when we use `cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C` , a weighted mean is calculated. But how do I see or change the weights used for calculating the weighted mean?

Comment: Yes you can use `cv2.filter2D()`. Check out [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cv2.getGaussianKernel()` to see the weights assigned to your function.

`cv2.get GaussianKernel() accepts 3 parameters:

1. **kernel_size**: size of the kernel (must be odd)
2. **sigma**: standard deviation of the Gaussian window used. It is calculated by this formula: 0.3*((kernel_size-1)*0.5 - 1) + 0.8
3. **type**: type of the coefficients (either `float32` or `float64`)

Details of this method is given on [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaussiankernel)

**Example:**

Consider the following to be the setting for `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()`:

```
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

Here the kernel size is 11. You can get the corresponding weights as said above:

```
cv2.getGaussianKernel(11, 2)
```

which returns an array where the central position has the highest value:

```
array([[ 0.00881223],
       [ 0.02714358],
       [ 0.06511406],
       [ 0.12164907],
       [ 0.17699836],
       [ 0.20056541],
       [ 0.17699836],
       [ 0.12164907],
       [ 0.06511406],
       [ 0.02714358],
       [ 0.00881223]])
```

The weights can be altered by varying the *sigma* value which is the second parameter in `cv2.getGaussianKernel()`:

```
cv2.getGaussianKernel(11, 3)
```

returns the following weights:

```
array([[ 0.03548293],
       [ 0.05850147],
       [ 0.08630959],
       [ 0.1139453 ],
       [ 0.13461047],
       [ 0.14230046],
       [ 0.13461047],
       [ 0.1139453 ],
       [ 0.08630959],
       [ 0.05850147],
       [ 0.03548293]])
```